# PLSQL query to search through table type

Tags: plsql, cursor, erp

I have declared the following types in a package.

```
TYPE l_task_type_rec is record (task_id number, creation_date date);

TYPE tas_tab is table of l_task_type_rec;

l_task_rec tas_tab;
```

I am trying to use a for loop to iterate through the objects in the table type objects like this. I am not sure if it is possible.

```
for counter in l_task_rec.first ..l_task_rec.last

loop

    select task_id into l_task_id from l_task_rec where rowid = counter;

    select location_id into p_location_id from csf_ct_tasks where task_id = l_task_id;

    OPEN c_location_rec (p_location_id);

                    FETCH c_location_rec

                    BULK COLLECT INTO x_location_rec;

     CLOSE c_location_rec;

end loop;
```

What I want is to call a cursor from inside the for loop so that I can get a list of all the locations one by one and fetch and store all the data in a record type. I know the query to search the table type is wrong because it says the table or view l_task_rec does not exist! Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here or point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can iterate through objects in the table type:

```
declare
  l_task_rec tas_tab;
  p_location_id number;//Assuming number
begin
  --Example data
  l_task_rec:=tas_tab( l_task_type_rec (10, sysdate), l_task_type_rec (21, sysdate), l_task_type_rec (35, sysdate));--This should come from somewhere else

  for counter in l_task_rec.first .. l_task_rec.last
  loop
    --You can get the data like this
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TASK_ID: '||l_task_rec(counter).TASK_ID);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CREATION_DATE: '||l_task_rec(counter).CREATION_DATE);

    select location_id into p_location_id from csf_ct_tasks where task_id = l_task_rec(counter).TASK_ID;
   --More code
   --OPEN  ...
   --CLOSE ...
  end loop;
end;
```

In order for this to work, I changed how `l_task_type_rec` type is created:

```
create TYPE l_task_type_rec is object (task_id number, creation_date date)
```

Comment: Hi, using your code i can iterate through the loop. But the data that i need to select or print is inside the nested table l_task_rec. Currently i am using the following query which returns the error 

"ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete"                                                       select task_id into l_task_id from table(l_task_rec) where rownum = counter;

Comment: Getting the data inside the nested table `l_task_rec` is explained in the answer: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TASK_ID: '||l_task_rec(counter).TASK_ID);`. However, in order to get that nested table from inside a record in another table, you can get it like any other column `SELECT task_rec into l_task_rec from the_table where id=X`